# $\frac{N}{11}$ is equal with summation of squars(power of two) of digits of $N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to find 3-digits number $N$ such that

$I)$ $11|N$

$II)$ $\frac{N}{11}$ is equal with summation of squars(power of two) of digits of $N$

Comment: There are only 900 3-digit numbers, only about 80 of them are multiples of 11, you could just try all 80 of them to see which ones work.

Comment: 550 is the only such number!

Comment: Hint: try to solve one of following diophantine equations for $x,y,z $ positive $\leq10$
$$100x+10y+z=11N=11(x^2+y^2)=11(x^2+z^2)=11(y^2+z^2)$$

Comment: @Inc, care to share your method?

Comment: @Inceptio:  I find $803=11\cdot 73=11(8^2+3^2)$ as well.

Comment: I missed it. Thanks for noticing that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Reading the equation 
$$(N:=)\quad 100x+10y+z=11m$$
modulo $11$ gives $x-y+z=0$ $\ {\rm mod}\ 11$, or one of
$${\rm (i)}\ x=y-z, \qquad {\rm (ii)}\  x=y-z+11\ ,$$
taking into account the condition $1\leq x\leq 9$.

In case (i) we obtain $m=10y-9z$, so that $m=x^2+y^2+z^2$ leads to
$$2y^2-2yz+2z^2-10y+9z=0\ .$$
Solving this for $y$ we obtain
$$y={1\over2}\left(5+z\pm\sqrt{25-8z-3z^3}\right)\ .$$
This gives integer values only for $z=0$, namely $y=0$ and $y=5$. The first of these leads together with (i) to $x=0$, which is forbidden, so that in  case (i) we are left with $N=550$, which is easily verified to be a solution of the original problem.

In case (ii) we obtain $m=10y-9z+100$, so that $m=x^2+y^2+z^2$ leads to
$$2y^2-2yz+2z^2+12y-13z+21=0\ .$$
Solving this for $z$ we obtain
$$z={1\over4}\left(13+2y\pm\sqrt{1-44y-12y^2}\right)\ ,$$
which obviously forces $y=0$ and therefore $z=3$ or $z={7\over2}$. The first of these leads together with (ii) to $N=803$, which is easily verified to be a solution of the original problem.

Comment: a little wrong; in fact we have:$y=\frac 12 (5+z\pm \sqrt{25-8z-3z^2}) , z=\frac 14 (4y+13\pm \sqrt{1-104y})$

Comment: @agustin: I think it's correct. When solving for $z$ there's got to be some $y^2$'s under the root sign.

Answer (score 1):

To try all $81$ is easy in a spreadsheet.  I made a column starting with $110$ and adding $11$ each row.  The next three columns extracted the digits of the number and the last column had the number divided by $11$ minus the squares of each digit.  It finds $550$ and $803$ as solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an IMO $1960$ question. This has been discussed in **AOPS**. [Determine all three-digit numbers $N$ having the property that  $N$ is divisible by $11$, and $\dfrac{N}{11}$ is equal to the sum of the squares of the digits of $N$.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/1960_IMO_Problems/Problem_1)